# Windows Server 2008 Hyper-V Server: Guest Windows Server machine imported - only see blinking underscore

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, virtualization

I exported 2 virtual PCs from Hyper-V. and then imported them. I can't start one virtual machine that has Windows Server 2008 R2 installed. The machine starts, but then I only see a blinking underscore.  I am trying to run these virtual PCs on Hyper-V 2008 R2 that is installed on bare metal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load installation CD / DVD run repair and cmd and

`bootrec /fixmbr`

`bootrec /fixboot`

`bootrec /ScanOs`

`bootrec /RebuildBCD`

saved my life....

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your boot order for the virtual machine?  I have had this happen with bad ISO or image files and the virtual machine trying to boot from them.  You can check the boot order from the Action menu for the Hyper-V Manager.

Comment: I exported that machine. Tried several times to prevent bad export. Imported on another machine, and not working here. Link to vhd file seems to be ok too...

Comment: Changing boot order didn't helped...

Comment: Boot from the 2008r2 DVD and attempt a boot repair or a repair installation.  This will at least show whether the vhd file is connected and working.

Comment: Win repair didn't helped. But in repair, I ran cmd and
 
`bootrec /fixmbr`
`bootrec /fixboot`
`bootrec /ScanOs`
`bootrec /RebuildBCD`  solved my problem.....

Comment: Well done.  Now why is exporting your VHDs causing the bootmgr to loose your info?  I have seen this happen when exporting from HyperV on 2008 and importing them on HyperV 2008R2...

Comment: Have no idea. I exported from win server 2008 R2 and imported to hyperv 2008 server.